# python : How to get all the values from a list of a list excluding a certain value and then get the mean of each column?

Tags: python

I would be grateful if someone could help me to get the mean value of each column excluding number 6. So in the following example, I should get [2,6,4.5]
because for the 1st column, when I exclude 6, mean is just (2/1)=2
for the second column,((3+9)/2)=6, for the 3rd column , ((4+5)/2)=4.5

Here is my code to get mean for each column, without excluding 6

```
def mean(x):
    return sum(x) / float(len(x))


x = [[2,3,4],[6,9,5]] 
b = map(mean, zip(*x))
print (b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply take the transpose, using the `x_t = zip(*x)` transpose idiom, then *filter and map*, here using a list-comprehension:

```
>>> [mean([i for i in sub if i !=6]) for sub in zip(*x)]
[2.0, 6.0, 4.5]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response Juanpa.

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda b:sum(b)/float(len(b)), map(lambda y:filter(lambda a:a!=6, y), zip(*x)))
```